# Docker container on Raspberry Pi 4: standard_init_linux.go:228: exec user process caused: exec format error

Tags: .net, docker, dockerfile, raspberry-pi4, docker-image

first of all: I'm pretty new to docker and building my own images etc. So please, if I did an obvious mistake don't go crazy :D.
I already tried every "solution" I found but either i didn't get it right or it won't work in my case.

I made a dotnet core webapp (.net6.0) on Visual Studio 2022 but i cannot run the container on my Raspberry Pi 4. It always stops the containers immediately and says

```
standard_init_linux.go:228: exec user process caused: exec format error
```

My dockerfile looks like this:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0-focal AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0-focal AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["WebApp/WebApp.csproj", "WebApp/"]
COPY ["WebApp.Models/WebAppModels.csproj", "WebApp.Models/"]
RUN dotnet restore "WebApp/WebApp.csproj" -r linux-arm64
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/WebApp"
RUN dotnet build "WebApp.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build -r linux-arm64

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "WebApp.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish -r linux-arm64

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "WebApp.dll"]
```

In Visual Studio i set

```
Platform target = ARM64
```

I tried it using the publish function of Visual Studio with ***TargetRuntime = win-arm64***

Via CMD i tried docker build with ***--platform linux/arm64***

Both images won't run on my Raspberry.

Does anybody know how to get this working?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You've got the wrong architecture set. You're publishing it as arm64 but Raspberry Pi is arm32. You should have better luck if you just search-and-replace "arm64" with "arm32" in your Dockerfile.